# Error in MySQL syntax when i try to create database and set user privileges through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is the first time that i will ask a question in this forum.

I am working on a php project in which i have to -through php- create a database and   insert some empty tables.

The issue here is that i always get an error message regarding syntax when i try to add privileges to the superuser (for some reason, if i don't, an error message states that i don't have permition to access the database).

Here is the code for creating the database and assigning privileges:

```
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `database` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci; "; 

$sql .= "GRANT SELECT database.* TO 'superuser'@'localhost' ";

$sql .= "GRANT ALL ON database." TO 'superuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; ";

$sql .= "FLUSH PRIVILEGES";
```

Can you tell me what did wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most database libraries allow only one query at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to end each of your SQL statements with a semi colon `;`, it is missing after the first `GRANT`. The second `GRANT` uses `database."` and should be `database.*`, should also be surrounded by backticks as "database" is a reserved word. That said, the first `GRANT` can be omitted as the it will be included with `GRANT ALL`.

```
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `database` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci; ";
$sql .= "GRANT ALL ON `database`.* TO 'superuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; ";
$sql .= "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;";
```

You can also use a [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) format to make it easier to read

```
$sql = <<<SQL
  CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `database` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
  GRANT ALL ON `database`.* TO 'superuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES; 
SQL;
```

Comment: There is one missing after your first GRANT statement

Comment: when i add the semicolon, i get an error message tha the query has failed

Comment: Please see my last edits, there were actually several errors in your example.

Comment: $sql = <<<SQL
  CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS 'strongim_$this->title' DEFAULT  CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
GRANT ALL ON 'strongim_pmsimple_$this->title'.* TO 'DB_USER'@'DB_SERVER' IDENTIFIED BY 'DB_PASS';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES; 
SQL;

Comment: DB_USER, DB_SERVER and DB_PASS are defined variables

Comment: This is not your original question there are additional errors in the PHP in your comment. You can't include variables inside single quotes, you can't reference and object property inside a string without curly braces and you are treating the user/server/pass as strings, not variables.

Comment: Tnks for the Help. The truth is i am still getting syntax errors and i tried everything..

Comment: Thank you for your time doublesharp! Al least now i'm closer to the answer